# Capybara unable to pick up hidden element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, hover, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Pretty simple spec is failing after upgrade (Rails 4.2 -> 5.2) and Capybara (2.x to 3.10.1).

I think it might have something to do with the way `.hover` is being used to make a hidden element appear on mouseover, but I could be wrong?!?

The "1" bubble appears when driver is manually paused right before "expect(…)" . However, I'm not sure Capybara's `.hover` is working in the spec. Is there any other way to do do this?

RSpec:

```
scenario 'changes counter' do
  close_modal type: :image

  find('editable-section:nth-child(1) li.photo:nth-child(1)').hover

  save_and_open_page # <- `1` is visible on the page (see HTML below)

  within 'editable-section:nth-child(1) li.photo:nth-child(1)' do
    expect(page).to have_css '.comment-count', text: '1'
  end
end
```

Failure:

```
  1) Comment creation for image changes counter
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css '.comment-count', text: '1'
       expected to find visible css ".comment-count" with text "1" within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="li" path="/HTML/BODY/DIV[2]/SECTION/DIV/EDITABLE-SECTION[1]/DIV/DIV/DIV/SECTION/UL/LI"> but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

It doesn't even respond to:

```
pry> expect(page).to have_css('.comment-count')
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find visible css ".comment-count" but there were no matches. Also found "", "", "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

HTML from Chrome paused right before `expect` shows that `.comment-count` is clearly there:

```
<ul attachments="section.attachments" class="collage ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" image-collage="" ng-if="isDisplaying">
  <!-- ngRepeat: attachment in section.attachments -->
  <li class="photo ng-scope" ng-repeat="attachment in section.attachments" style="width: 299px; height: 300px; margin-bottom: 9.6px; margin-right: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="meta-indicator">
      <div class="comment-count">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
        <span ng-bind="attachment.commentsCount" class="ng-binding">1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="image-wrapper" href="">
      <img ng-click="openModal(attachment)" ng-src="https://d545dpp7432ym.cloudfront.net/images/medium/test-image.jpg" role="button" tabindex="0" src="https://d545dpp7432ym.cloudfront.net/images/medium/test-image.jpg" style="width: 299px; height: 300px;">
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: attachment in section.attachments -->
</ul>
```

CSS (slim):

```
  ul.collage(image-collage attachments="section.attachments" ng-if="isDisabled")
    li.photo ng-repeat="attachment in section.attachments"
      .meta-indicator
        .comment-count
          i.fa.fa-comment
          span ng-bind="attachment.commentsCount"

      a.image-wrapper href=""
        img(
          ng-src="{{ attachment.mediaFile.previewUrl('medium') }}"
        )

  ul.collage(image-collage attachments="section.attachments" ng-if="isDisplaying")
    li.photo ng-repeat="attachment in section.attachments"
      .meta-indicator
        .comment-count
          i.fa.fa-comment
          span ng-bind="attachment.commentsCount"

      a.image-wrapper href=""
        img(
          ng-src="{{ attachment.mediaFile.previewUrl('medium') }}"
          ng-click="openModal(attachment)"
        )
```

**Edit:** Add Chrome dev inspection

What's happening if I stop the test after `find('...').hover` the element is visible but the element is not revealed. If i manually hover the mouse at this point or force a `:hover` (as seen in image) then the test proceeds immediately and passes.

It is finding the element, as replacing `.hover` with `.click` opens the modal. Something about `.hover` is not working. Is that any other way to automate a `:hover` event?

[image]

Comment: As asked on your previous question about the same issue which you didn't respond to - What do you have Capybara.default_max_wait_time set to?

Comment: Also - you can't trust `save_and_open_page` for visibility issues, because it saves HTML attributes not properties, and isn't always able to load the CSS. Instead just pause your test and look at the browser to see whether the count is visible.  The error message is telling you that it's finding 3 elements that match `.comment-count' but they are not visible or the text doesn't match '1'  -- are you sure you're selecting within the correct element (maybe add more of the HTML to the question)??

Comment: `default_max_wait_time = 10`

Comment: Ok -- you show two different error messages - one has "" and one has "","",""  - so one is finding one element that matches '.comment-count' and the other is finding 3 (none are actually visible though) -- why the difference?

Comment: How is the visibility handled? Is it through CSS or is it via a JS library?  If JS what events is it dependent on?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks for your help! The second example was from `pry` and outside the `within` block. I put a `binding.pry` a line above the `within` block when trying to troubleshoot this.   Also, driver is `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless`. What would you recommend if I were to pause & view output as you mention above?

Comment: Swap to non-headless so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Added some CSS (slim)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/twalpole/4252d0b51ddec41543a09d3d53256d21 shows that if the HTML/CSS you posted is all that's going on Capybara has no issue finding the .comment-count element with text of "1" - This would imply there is more happening on the page than is shown in the info currently provided -- Without a lot more info or an example that reproduces your issue there's not much more that can be suggested.  You could try sleeping for second after the hover and then using save_and_open_screenshot to see if the text is actually becoming visible

Comment: Appreciate effort in trying to help. I've had others look at this and it's puzzling.  Something about `.hover` just isn't working for me here. I've added image from Chrome dev tools. There is AngularJS on this page though not sure how to test if that's interfering somehow.  Reminder, these specs passed fine in Rails 4.2 and Capybara 2.x. <sigh>

Comment: When is that image from?  From the tests, or from when you manually moved the mouse over whatever the hover is? Also, you never answered how the changing visibility of the item is handled -- is it via a css :hover selector or is it via JS - if JS what events is it dependent on?  (Note nothing has changed in how `hover` is implemented from the ruby side - it is possible it changed from the chromedriver side -- were you using the current version of chromedriver with Rails 4.2 and Capybara 2.x?)

Comment: Also, did you try a screenshot from the test?  Was the element visible in that?

Comment: Is the page you're testing publicly accessible somewhere so I can try it?  From your picture it seems like the visibility is based on CSS :hover selector which the `.hover` method should definitely trigger.

Comment: element is visible when Chrome is paused AND with save_and_open_page (although in this case page has no CSS so though `1` is visible it's not over/in the image it's above it.  We were using Poltergeist but switched to Chromedriver because of Poltergeist issues when upgrading to Rails 5.2.